# Why is cperl-mode-hook running twice?

Tags: hooks, major-mode

I am using `cperl-mode` to edit Perl scripts. According to the Emacs wiki ( [link](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CPerlMode) ) one could use `defalias` to use `cperl-mode` instead of `perl-mode`. Here is an example:

```
$ emacs -Q -l init.el test.pl &
```

where `init.el` is:

```el
(defalias 'perl-mode 'cperl-mode)
(defun my-test-hook ()
  (message-box (symbol-name major-mode)))
(add-hook 'cperl-mode-hook #'my-test-hook)
```

This gives two message boxes, indicating that the hook `my-test-hook` is being run twice at startup.. (I also tested this with `emacs-lisp-mode` (without using `defalias` of course) and then the hook was run only a single time, as expected.. So that was what lead me to suspect `defalias` was the culprit).

Why is the hook being run twice here? (I am asking because I would like to have it run only a single time if possible)

Comment: I really doubt the `defalias` plays any role here. `cperl-mode-hook` variable is just a variable (possibly autoloaded), adding an alias to a function `cperl-mode` shouldn't affect it at all.  I'd try to debug the `cperl-mode` function instead--maybe it runs the hooks twice in some cases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a bug in `cperl-mode`. It is defined using `define-derived-mode`, a special form that defines a mode. When using it, it generates code to call the mode hook. However, the body of also contain an explicit call to the hooks, so it will be called twice.